# Thread1:EXC_BAd_InSTRUCTION(code =EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, uialertsheet, nsrunalertpanel

I'm new to Cocoa, xcode.I'm Doing Sample Project " How to display AlertPanel and Alert Sheets.I am Getting Error Like this "thread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=...).Here i Mentioned the Code line where i got the error.Please help me out.

```
Alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(window,completionhandler:{(code:NSMOdalResponse)-> void in.
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSAlert beginSheetModalForWindow` is for Mac OS development.

As you mentioned `iPhone` as a tag to this question, I assume you are developing iOS application. For iOS development, use `UIAlertController`. Here is the sample code:

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                            //Handel yes button action here
                        }];
   UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"No"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                               //Handel no button action here
                           }];

   [alert addAction:yesButton];
   [alert addAction:noButton];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For more details, refer [Apple iOS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry ,unfortunately i tagged iphone,actually i am creating  sample project for mac os and using the Xcode(7.3.1) IDE.please help me.